# Modelica - Dymola Python interface: Set output format to textual

Tags: python, output, modelica, dymola

I am running Modelica simulations with Dymola via the Dymola Python interface. My aim is to have the result file written to textual output (i.e. to a `.txt` file). Even though my model contains the annotation `__Dymola_experimentSetupOutput(textual=true, events=false)`, the output is written to a `.mat` file. Unfortunately, when I type `find()` into the Dymola command line, I cannot find a suitable flag for setting the output format via `dymola.ExecuteCommand()`.

Is there a possibility to set the output format to textual via the Python interface? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set textual output in the python interface with

```
dymola.experimentSetupOutput(textual=True)
```