# Dymola with python interface - plotting the results to a text file (.txt) or something similar

Tags: python, output, modelica, dymola

I'm running this example (see below) from the dymola python interface, how can I plot/store the output in a table/text-file or something similar?

```
from dymola.dymola_interface import DymolaInterface
from dymola.dymola_exception import DymolaException

dymola = None
try:
    # Instantiate the Dymola interface and start Dymola
    dymola = DymolaInterface()

    # Call a function in Dymola and check its return value
    result = dymola.simulateModel("Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Examples.CoupledClutches")
    if not result:
        print("Simulation failed. Below is the translation log.")
        log = dymola.getLastError()
        print(log)
        exit(1)

    dymola.plot(["J1.w", "J2.w", "J3.w", "J4.w"])
    dymola.ExportPlotAsImage("C:/temp/plot.png")
    print("OK")
except DymolaException as ex:
    print("Error: " + str(ex))
finally:
    if dymola is not None:
        dymola.close()
        dymola = None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Dymola Manual Volume 2, "Section 6.7 Python Interface for Dymola" (which the posted example seems to come from), you can find an example related to Multithreading. In this example you can find a way to create plots directly.

There is a nice tool which can be found at https://www.j-raedler.de/projects/dymat/. You can use that to read the default result file (this is the file #ModelName#.mat which is stored in the working directory) efficiently further process it in Python.

To switch from the default .mat file to a text-based file you can find the command here: [Modelica - Dymola Python interface: Set output format to textual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202469/modelica-dymola-python-interface-set-output-format-to-textual)

There are other ways as well, but this should be fine as a first step...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think you misunderstood my question. I want to start the simulation via python and store the results not only in a plot, but also in a table or something similar to compare the results to others. Is there a possibility to do both, simulating models + analyzing results?

Comment: And I don't get where I have to "put" the piece of code mentioned in the post "Modelica - Dymola Python interface: Set output format to textual".

Comment: By calling _simulateModel_ you get the simulation results as .mat file in the Dymola working directory. The post "Modelica - Dymola Python interface: Set output format to textual" explains how to get the simulation results as .txt file instead of .mat. You can add the code anywhere before calling _simulateModel_

Comment: When adding the code above "try:" and  define dymola as Dymolainterface() the simulation runs without errors, but I can't find a result .txt file. When adding the code under "try" (before simulateModel) I get the following Error: "C:\Python27>python.exe DymolaExample.py
  File "DymolaExample.py", line 8
    dymola.experimentSetupOutput(textual=True)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent"

Comment: Did you check the working directory for the .mat file? I suggest you change the working directory manually with _dymola.cd("C:/temp/dymola")_, then you should have a dsre.mat in the temp folder

Comment: Adding the code _dymola.experimentSetupOutput(textual=True)_ before creating the dymola interface object has no effect. Add it after _dymola = DymolaInterface()_ and check that you have the correct indent of 4 spaces. Your error message sound like you don't have that.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you so much! The problem was that I used Tab instead of 4 spaces.